# My InStr keeps telling me its mismatched

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
 englishReasonsToGoToSecondFloor = "test" & ";" & "exam & pay" & ";" & " possible fake"
```

So my values may contain a **&** or (space) or just a single word. Each item is separated by a ";"

so the final list will look like "test;exam & pay;possible fake"

When the user selects an item from the Listbox, I want to quickly compare the selection with the words in the variable

```
rowValue = Trim(listboxTest.Column(1))
englishResult = InStr(rowValue, englishReasonsToGoToSecondFloor, CompareMethod.Text)
```

I can mouse over the rowValue and I see there is a value.

I've also tried with

```
englishResult = InStr(rowValue, englishReasonsToGoToSecondFloor, vbTextCompare)
```

Error message is "Run-time error '13'

Comment: `If Instr(1, "String", "Substring to search for", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then` is the way I usually use InStr. I have never experienced an error with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the help for `InStr()`. Or [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/InStr-Function-85d3392c-3b1c-4232-bb18-77cd0cb8a55b) .

```
 InStr ([start, ] string1, string2 [, compare ] )
```

> The start argument is required if compare is specified.

So leave out the `compare` argument, or supply `start`.

And you have the string arguments mixed up (I need to remind myself of the correct order pretty often too).

> string1 - Required. String expression being searched.
>   string2 - Required. String expression sought.

So you want

```
englishResult = InStr(1, englishReasonsToGoToSecondFloor, rowValue, vbTextCompare)
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed that so many times. I added the start position as 1. However the result is always 0 and I can see the result within string2 (since its hard-coded). Am I missing something else?

Comment: See edit. My German reminder is "DURCHsuchter string, GEsuchter string". :)

Comment: I corrected my code to include a start string. but why swap rowValue with englishReasons...?