# My InStr is always returning 0

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
 englishReasonsToGoToSecondFloor = "test" & ";" & "exam & pay" & ";" & " possible fake"
```

So my values may contain a **&** or (space) or just a single word. Each item is separated by a ";"

so the final list will look like "test;exam & pay;possible fake" (the real list is much longer)

When the user selects an item from the Listbox, I want to quickly compare the selection with the words in the variable (if there is a better way to compare, please let me know)

```
rowValue = Trim(listboxTest.Column(1))
englishResult = InStr(1, rowValue, englishReasonsToGoToSecondFloor, CompareMethod.Text)
```

I can mouse over the rowValue and I see there is a value.

```
rowValue contains "possible fake"
```

but the englishResult is always 0

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it like that as you're looking for the full string, the & concatenates them like "test;examp & pay; possible fake" which is what you'll look for, I think you'll need to run more than one instr.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353529/my-instr-keeps-telling-me-its-mismatched posted half hour earlier.  Was going to say exact duplicate but last three lines are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be like below

```
englishResult = InStr(1, englishReasonsToGoToSecondFloor, rowValue, CompareMethod.Text)
```

---

**EDIT**

The Syntax for Instr function is

```
InStr( [Start], String1, String2, [Compare] )
```

> where,
>
> [Start]    -   An optional integer argument, representing the position that you want to start searching from. If omitted, the [Start] argument takes on the default value of 1.
>
> String1    -   The string that you want to search.
>
> String2    -   The substring that you want to search for.
>
> [Compare]  -   An optional argument, specifying the type of comparison to make.
>   This can be any of the following values:
>
> vbBinaryCompare    -   performs a binary comparison
>
> vbTextCompare  -   performs a text comparison
>
> vbDatabaseCompare  -   performs a database comparison
>
> > If omitted, the [Compare] argument takes on the default value vbBinaryCompare.

Comment: For the sake of future readers, can you explain why this solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

not sure about Access.. but the Instr method works in Excel VBA with a master string before the search string so

`InStr(1,englishReasonsToGoToSecondFloor, rowValue , CompareMethod.Text)` this should work.

Answer (score -1):

`englishResult = InStr(1,  rowValue,"test", CompareMethod.Text)
if englishResult=0 then englishResult = InStr(1,rowValue,  "exam & pay", CompareMethod.Text)
if englishResult=0 then englishResult = InStr(1, rowValue, " possible fake",  rowValue,CompareMethod.Text)`